# trying to pip install numpy with pydroid, OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module

Tags: android, numpy, pip, cython, pydroid

I have pydroid pro. When I tried to install the numpy and cv2 libraries, `pip` failed and gave me this error (see screenshot)

`OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module`

I tried to install via the terminal and it didn't work either

[image: 1]

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. screenshots of text are bad for various reasons. please replace by the contained text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go to play store and search for pydroid repository plugin. Download that and go to your pydroid app  select pip then go to quick install and select numpy. That's it you can use internet connection when selecting numpy.